# Django Import Error at / No module named urls

Tags: python, django, django-urls, gunicorn

I have changed the URLs in the website file, now, the page doesn't work.
This is the error I get.
[image]

I'm using Django 1.8.7 on Ubuntu 16.04, on a DigitalOcean Droplet and it is hosted on Gunicorn.

This is my project url file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('website.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is website urls file:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'^en/$', views.index_en, name='index_en'),
                  url(r'^en/results/$', views.results_en, name="results_en"),
                  url(r'^es/$', views.index_es, name='index_es'),
                  url(r'^es/results/$', views.results_es, name="results_es"),
              ] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

My settings.py, it is the default settings generated when i created the droplet, i only changed the language code and the static content directory:

```
    import os

    BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
    SECRET_KEY = 'itisasecrethahaha'

    DEBUG = True

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


    # Application definition

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
        'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'website'
    )

    MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
        'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
        'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
        'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    )

    ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project.urls'

    TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]

    WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project.wsgi.application'

    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
        }
    }

    LANGUAGE_CODE = 'es-es'

    TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

    USE_I18N = True

    USE_L10N = True

    USE_TZ = True

    STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
    STATIC_URL = '/assets/'

    import os
    import netifaces

   def ip_addresses():
        ip_list = []
        for interface in netifaces.interfaces():
            addrs = netifaces.ifaddresses(interface)
            for x in (netifaces.AF_INET, netifaces.AF_INET6):
                if x in addrs:
                    ip_list.append(addrs[x][0]['addr'])
        return ip_list

    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ip_addresses()
```

My project tree:
[image]

The traceback:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://206.189.31.17/

Django Version: 1.8.7
Python Version: 2.7.12
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'website')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  119.                 resolver_match = resolver.resolve(request.path_info)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  365.             for pattern in self.url_patterns:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in url_patterns
  401.         patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in urlconf_module
  395.             self._urlconf_module = import_module(self.urlconf_name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py" in import_module
  37.     __import__(name)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/builtins.py" in __import__
  93.             result = _import(*args, **kwargs)

Exception Type: ImportError at /
Exception Value: No module named urls
```

Comment: Can you post your settings?

Comment: What's the name of your project and the value set to `ROOT_URLCONF` in the settings.py file ?

Comment: could you post your directory tree?

Comment: try `ROOT_URLCONF = 'urls'`

Comment: @Rakesh it doesnt work :(

Comment: @seuling there you go :)

Comment: Can you restart your Gunicorn deamon ? and try again?

Comment: @ChihebNexus i do that everytime i make a change :( systemctl restart gunicorn.service, right?

Comment: could you upload your `django_project/urls.py`? <= never mind I found it above

Comment: try to delete `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)` in `webstie/urls.py`

Comment: @seuling same :(

Comment: Is it working when remove `url(r'^', include('website.urls')),` in your project urls.py?

Comment: @seuling nop, says the same error

Comment: wierd.. is there somewhere else you import `urls`? like `reverse`

Comment: @seuling i dont think so... it worked yesterday, i changed the website.urls file to include the es and en, before it only was / and /results, now is /es and /en, for different languages, once i changed that it stopped working.

Comment: omg it worked yesterday? But you said that it worked without `website.urls`. Just remove all app from project and try again. is it work?

Comment: @seuling the website.urls was url(r'^/$', views.index, name='index') and url(r'^results/$', views.results, name="results"), it worked yesterday, but when i changed to the new configuration that you can see in the question, inmediately it stopped working. I didnt changed the urls.py from the project. I have deleted the website directory from the project, now it says 502 Bad Gateway.

Comment: If something wrong with change website.urls, I mean just go back to that code and see working well. If it works, you can specify your problem. can you change your code right before the error occurs?

Comment: @seuling I got that error trying to create again the app website https://imgur.com/a/kvPocvr

Comment: Then maybe your code still include import website. or installed app. And you don't have to use `createapp` to create app. it's just helper.

Comment: I solved the error of the app, I go back to the previous website.urls, the error persists >.< You can access the webpage here: [link](http://206.189.31.17/)

Comment: ok let's start again. first, please go back to yesterday's code for seeing other code working

Comment: @seuling i went back, the erros is here too, i dont know why. Now the error remains.

Comment: Then I guess it's not the error of `website.urls`. It came from other. If you're using git, just clear that everything is go back to yesterday include settings. If the code is totally same, the problem is from outside - like gunicorn, or virtualenv

Comment: @seuling The code is totally the same, Im getting frutated...

Comment: Relax buddy. You can solve your problem. Just check things one by one. You use python 2.7 and django 1.8.7, right? Do you use virtualenv in server?

Comment: @seuling Yes, i use python 2.7 and Django 1.8.7. I dont think i use virtualenv, the project is runned by nginx and gunicorn, i dont know if they use venv. The settings from nginx and gunicorn are the default setting created while the droplet is created.

Comment: Can you access shell in server? `python manage.py shell`

Comment: @seuling yes i can

Comment: Weird.. you can call urls in shell too, right? Then check your `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE`. I thought you don't have one, so find in `wsgi.py` and what's your module settings. It should be `django_project.settings`

Comment: @seuling Yes,i have it https://imgur.com/a/KLgQ0bj

Comment: @JoeSanz Did you solve your problem?

Comment: @seuling yes, i will post the resolve right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem, just reinstalling the Droplet on DigitalOcean and recreating everything.

Answer (score 0):

add this line in your project urls.py file

`from website import urls as website_urls`

and change

`url(r'^', include('website.urls'))`

`url(r'^', include('website_urls'))`

Comment: Same error. I will edit my question to let you know the traceback.